# How to moq a SslStream in unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, sslstream

I would like to mock `AuthenticateAsClientAsync` method in the `SslStream` class. I also want to mock the different security cases used by the SslStream for example: `IsAuthenticated`, `IsEncrypted` and `IsSigned`. Mocking seems possible, because the method and the properties are **virtual** or **override**.

```
internal bool AuthenticateSSLStream(SslStream sslStream)
{
    string certName = myCertificate.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false);
    bool isAuthenticationCompleted = sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(certName,
        new X509Certificate2Collection(myCertificate), SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12, true).Wait(10000);
    if (!isAuthenticationCompleted || !sslStream.IsAuthenticated || !sslStream.IsEncrypted || !sslStream.IsSigned)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException("Authentication is not succeeded!");
    }

    return isAuthenticationCompleted;
}
```

I have created a method and pass a SslStream in order to mock it. A `X509Certificate2` certificate was passed through the constructor and stored in the variable name `myCertificate`.

How can I coverage all cases of the condition? How to reach the authentication exception using moq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to mock with the [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) framework. The `SslStream` constructor accepts a `Stream` for sending and receiving data.

- Step one is to create a **streamMock**.
- Secondly, create a **sslStreamMock** and passed the mocked Stream object instance to the **sslStreamMock**.
- Next, setup the specific method and property.

  ```
    private Mock<SslStream> CreateSslStreamMock(Task task, bool isAuthenticated, bool isEncrypted, bool isSigned)
    {
        Mock<Stream> streamMock = new Mock<Stream>();
        streamMock.SetupGet(s => s.CanRead).Returns(true);
        streamMock.SetupGet(s => s.CanWrite).Returns(true);

        Mock<SslStream> sslStreamMock = new Mock<SslStream>(streamMock.Object);
        sslStreamMock.Setup(ss => ss.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(
            It.IsAny<string>(),
            It.IsAny<X509Certificate2Collection>(),
            It.IsAny<SslProtocols>(),
            It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(task);
        sslStreamMock.SetupGet(s => s.IsAuthenticated).Returns(isAuthenticated);
        sslStreamMock.SetupGet(s => s.IsEncrypted).Returns(isEncrypted);
        sslStreamMock.SetupGet(s => s.IsSigned).Returns(isSigned);

        return sslStreamMock;
    }
  ```

It is important to **streamMock** is readable and writable, otherwise `SslStream` constructor will throw ArgumentException, hence unable to create the mock object instance.